# How to give limit range using graph api to get limited feeds?

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

OpenFB.get('/v2.3/156501561036983/posts?fields=created_time,message,attachments&since: 1262304000&**limit>15&limit<25**')

I want to display facebook feeds in a particular range. Is it possible to give limit range in Url?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to display 15 more feeds when scroll reach to the end for lazy loading of feeds

Answer (score 0):

To get the next batch of results, you need to implement paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

Comment: How to use previous and next link in single url?

Comment: debug the result of your api call, there will be a next link in the resulting json. use that link as next api call.